# Desinstallation und Desaktivierung

Tags: word-choice, prefix, latin

Im Deutschen heißt es zum Beispiel *Desinfektion* und *Desillusion;* auf Grund der ersten Antwort wird wird also *kein* Fugen-S zwischen *de* und das Wort gesetzt, die Vorsilben de- und des- haben leicht abweichende Bedeutungen.

Bei Computern sagen aber alle *Deinstallation* und *Deaktivierung. Deaktivierung* hätte ich ja noch als Anglizismus verstanden *(deactivate),* aber *Deinstallation (uninstall)* nicht.

Es scheint auf die etymologische Fragestellung hinauszulaufen, warum es Deinstallation und nicht Desinstallation heißt – grammatikalisch läßt es sich wohl nicht erklären, wenn ich die bisherigen Ausführungen richtig verstanden haben sollte.

Comment: Dass jemand *deillusioniert* wirkt, kommt schon ab und an vor. (Auch wenn es nicht schön ist.)

Answer (score 21):

Man beachte, dass im Englischen auch *disinfected* und *disillusioned* auftreten.

Ein kurzer Blick in den Duden klärt die Ursache: Es handelt sich tatsächlich um zwei verschiedene Vorsilben, nicht um ein Fugen-S.

*Des-* kommt von lateinisch *dis-*

> 1. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass etwas aufgehoben, rückgängig gemacht wird
> 2. drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven das Aufheben oder Rückgängigmachen eines Vorganges oder dessen Ergebnisses aus
> 3. verneint in Bildungen mit **2. Partizipien** deren Bedeutung

*De-* kommt von lateinisch *de-* = von – weg

> 1. drückt in Bildungen mit Verben aus, dass etwas aufgehoben, rückgängig gemacht wird
> 2. drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven das Aufheben oder Rückgängigmachen eines Vorganges oder dessen Ergebnisses aus
> 3. verneint in Bildungen mit **Adjektiven** deren Bedeutung

Die Bedeutungen sind weitgehend identisch.

Comment: Das ist schon mal sehr erhellend - danke! Da 1. und 2. identisch und auf die beiden Fälle anwendbar sind: wer hat festgelegt, daß es _de-_ und nicht _des-_ sein muß? Gibt es eine etymologische Herleitung oder einen anderen guten Grund für _de-_?

Answer (score 1):

Im Deutschen dient ein Fugenlaut üblicherweise dazu, den Übergang von einem Teil zu einem anderen in einem zusammengesetzten Wort zu vereinfachen. Daraus lassen sich mehrere Argumente finden, warum die *Desinfektion* keinen Fugenlaut enthalten kann:

- Ein Fugenlaut soll die Aussprache der vorherigen Silbe nicht modifizieren; das gilt umso strenger bei einsilbigen Wörtern, die nur einen Stammvokal haben, wenn dabei Phoneme wechseln usw. *Des-* wird /dɛs/ ausgesprochen, während *De-* als /de:/ realisiert wird. /ɛ/ und /e:/ bilden allerdings ein phonetisches Minimalpaar (/bɛt/ versus /be:t/), ein Wechsel von Einem zum Anderen durch einen Fugenlaut ist extrem unwahrscheinlich)
- Es handelt sich um einsilbige Vorsilben. Diese werden im Deutschen üblicherweise nicht mit Fugenlauten angefügt.
- Beide Wortteile, Vorsilbe wie Stammwort, sind lateinisch. Eventuelle Fugenlaute sollten also nach lateinischen Regeln und nicht nach deutschen eintreten.

Comment: Auch sehr interessant! Jetzt brauchen wir möglicherweise nur noch einen Etymologen, der mir erklären kann, warum es "deinstallieren" und nicht "desinstallieren" heißt ... Danke für die Ausführungen!